# Filter out text

Tags: windows

I'm capturing a list of installed software when we refresh a computer so we can ensure the replacement gets the needed installs. I want to remove entries for pre-installed software. What I am doing now works, but I expect I'm doing it the hard way. I'm not adverse to calling PowerShell if that would be simpler.

Edit: Pre-installed software would include anything in the filters I am using here. Microsoft Office, Microsoft Visual Basic, Adobe Acrobat Reader, mcafee and so forth. The software list is initially captured to temp1.txt.

```
:: Filter out some unneeded entries
findstr /v /i /c:"security update" temp1.txt > temp2.txt
findstr /v /i /c:"service pack" temp2.txt > temp1.txt
findstr /v /i /c:"update for" temp1.txt > temp2.txt
findstr /v /i /c:"mcafee" temp2.txt > temp1.txt
findstr /v /i /c:"@C" temp1.txt > temp2.txt
findstr /v /i /c:"Intel" temp2.txt > temp1.txt
findstr /v /i /c:"Microsoft Office" temp1.txt > temp2.txt
findstr /v /i /c:"Microsoft Visual" temp2.txt > temp1.txt
findstr /v /i /c:"yyyy" temp1.txt > temp2.txt
findstr /v /i /c:"uuuu" temp2.txt > temp1.txt
findstr /v /i /c:"Conexant" temp1.txt > temp2.txt
findstr /v /i /c:"Adobe Acrobat Reader" temp2.txt > temp1.txt
findstr /v /i /c:"Apple Application" temp1.txt > temp2.txt
findstr /v /i /c:"Bonjour" temp2.txt > temp1.txt
findstr /v /i /c:"Cisco" temp1.txt > temp2.txt
findstr /v /i /c:"COV" temp2.txt > temp1.txt
findstr /v /i /c:"G Suite" temp1.txt > temp2.txt
findstr /v /i /c:"Google" temp2.txt > temp1.txt
findstr /v /i /c:"xxxx" temp1.txt > temp2.txt
findstr /v /i /c:"RSA" temp2.txt > temp1.txt
findstr /v /i /c:"Synaptics" temp1.txt > temp2.txt
findstr /v /i /c:"zzzz" temp2.txt > temp1.txt
findstr /v /i /c:"VLC" temp1.txt > temp2.txt
findstr /v /i /c:"VMware" temp2.txt > temp1.txt
findstr /v /i /c:"Vulkan" temp1.txt > temp2.txt
findstr /v /i /c:"Windows 10 Image Viewer" temp2.txt > temp1.txt
findstr /v /i /c:"Java" temp1.txt > temp2.txt
findstr /v /i /c:"Microsoft Access" temp2.txt > temp1.txt
findstr /v /i /c:"Microsoft DCF" temp1.txt > temp2.txt
findstr /v /i /c:"Microsoft Excel" temp2.txt > temp1.txt
findstr /v /i /c:"Microsoft Groove" temp1.txt > temp2.txt
findstr /v /i /c:"Microsoft InfoPath" temp2.txt > temp1.txt
findstr /v /i /c:"Microsoft OneNote" temp1.txt > temp2.txt
findstr /v /i /c:"Microsoft Outlook" temp2.txt > temp1.txt
findstr /v /i /c:"Microsoft PowerPoint" temp1.txt > temp2.txt
findstr /v /i /c:"Microsoft Publisher" temp2.txt > temp1.txt
findstr /v /i /c:"Microsoft Skype" temp1.txt > temp2.txt
findstr /v /i /c:"Microsoft Word" temp2.txt > temp1.txt
findstr /v /i /c:"Self-service" temp1.txt > temp2.txt
findstr /v /i /c:"Microsoft Silverlight" temp2.txt > installed_software.txt
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What software counts as pre-installed? You could just create an array listing all of the software that counts as pre-installed and filter that, I suppose. Please EDIT your question to make it more clear.

Comment: @JosefZ I don't know if that's necessary. We ask everyone asking scripting questions on SU to "show their work" so we can see what they've got. According to your standard, every one of those questions would then be off topic here.

Comment: To answer my question:
* Create a file named software_filters.txt withe the text to filter out
* Do a findstr that uses the file to filter the text:

`findstr /livg:software_filters.txt software1.txt > software2.txt'
`sort software2.txt /o installed_software.txt`